# C program is not reading redirected shell command standard input

Tags: c, bash, unix

I have compiled the below c code which should send any input it receives in standard input to standard output. It works as expected in the following scenarios:

```
[user@host ~]$ ./my_program
test...
test...
^C
[user@host ~]$ echo "Hello" | ./my_program
Hello
[user@host ~]$ ./my_program < test.txt
Contents of test.txt ...
```

However, if I redirect the output of a shell command into my program like so:

```
[user@host ~]$ ./my_program <(echo "Hello")
```

It does not output anything and waits for input as if I started the program with just `./my_program`

I expected an output of `Hello` and then the program to end. When I run the command `cat <(echo "Hello")` I get this expected result. What is causing the difference in behaviour between `cat` and `my_program`?

```
/* my_program.c */

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't redirect the `stdout` of the shell command like that. Do `echo "Hello" | ./my_program` instead.

Comment: Or `./my_program < <(echo "Hello")` -- note the extra `<` there not in the OP's command.

Comment: By doing `./my_program <(echo "Hello")` you are not redirecting stdin, you are substituting the results of the command by a file descriptor. If you want to redirect that file descriptor to stdin, you have to add the redirection: `./my_program < <(echo "Hello")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>Posting Community Wiki because the question is caused by a typo and thus off-topic.</sub>

---

You're passing a filename associated with a pipeline with the output of `echo "Hello"` on your program's command line, not attaching it to stdin.

To attach it to stdin you need an extra `<` on the command line:

```
./my_program < <(echo "Hello")
```

It works with `cat` the other way because when `cat` is passed command-line arguments, it treats them as files to read from.